# Xcode 8.2.1 & Swift 3.0.2 + Realm 2.4.x = Fatal Exception Crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, realm

So my Swift-based iOS app with no other non-native dependencies besides Realm is crashing fatally since Realm 2.4.

I first installed Realm 2.4.1 yesterday, saw the crash, and rolled back to 2.3 thinking it was a bug, so this is definitely occurring only with Realm 2.4 and onward.

But I just installed Realm 2.4.2 today, and I'm getting the same crash, which I can't figure out the cause of due to lack of information provided after the crash (empty debug console, nothing odd I can identify in threads).

When I remove the app from the simulator and then build from scratch, **the crash occurs on the last line** of my Realm setup code with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` error:

```
currentReminders = currentTab.reminders.sorted(byKeyPath: "reminderPosition", ascending: true)
```

On subsequent builds/launches without removing the app from the simulator, the crash and error message are the same, but it happens in a different place, though even then, it's on a line that attempts to get reminders from the `reminders` property in my `currentTab` object, which is a list of reminder objects.

Has anyone else encountered this or similar crashes since upgrading to Realm 2.4?

Comment: Have you tried performing a completely clean build (Product -> Clean)?

Comment: Doing a cleanup has resulted in a compilation error due `bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"` failing. I don't even remember why that bash command is necessary in the build phases, since I haven't had any troubles with it for ages.

Comment: That step is mentioned in the [Installation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation) section of the Realm documentation. It's necessary for app store submission as it removes the simulator architectures from the Realm frameworks. If it's failing it probably indicates that the Run Script Phase is running before the build phase that copies the frameworks into your app. You can drag the phase to move it to the bottom of the list of build phases.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I recall. Had to do that once before. No more crash either. Everything's working finally. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll move my comment to an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try performing a clean build. We've [seen reports](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4599#issuecomment-276231465) of Xcode failing to rebuild enough of the app when updating Realm versions, resulting in mysterious crashes. A clean build addresses those problems.